# Return a Record of Rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm attempting to write a `SELECT` query which returns a `RECORD` of `ROWS`.

I've solved half of the problem, as in I can get a RECORD to return a single ROW. But what about returning a set of ROWS?

Take the following query for example:

```
SELECT * FROM
  RECORD(
    (
      ROW(1::integer, 'Florida'::character varying)
    )
  ) AS tbl (id integer, state character varying)
```

I get what I anticipate:

```
+==============+
| id | state   |
+====+=========+
| 1  | Florida |
+----+---------+
```

However, when I attempt to add one additional ROW to the RECORD, this is where I encounter problems:

```
SELECT * FROM
  RECORD(
    (
      ROW(1::integer, 'Florida'::character varying),
      ROW(2::integer, 'Georgia'::character varying)
    )
  ) AS tbl (id integer, state character varying)
```

I would anticipate a result similar to:

```
+==============+
| id | state   |
+====+=========+
| 1  | Florida |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Georgia |
+----+---------+
```

However, I receive the following PostgreSQL errors instead:

```
********** Error **********
ERROR: function return row and query-specified return row do not match
SQL state: 42804
Detail: Returned type record at ordinal position 1, but query expects integer.
```

What is it I'm missing here? Something trivial, or am I approaching this all wrong? Any pointers or suggestions is greatly appreciated, and thank you!

On a related note: I understand that if this was to take place in a stored procedure I could return a `SETOF`, however for this use case I'm interested in returning a RECORD of ROWS directly through a query without the use of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this using the `row` constructor, but using the `values` clause, seems a lot easier (and cleaner) to me:

```
select * 
from (
  values 
    (1, 'Florida'),
    (2, 'Georgia')
) AS tbl (id, state);
```

or using a CTE

```
with tbl (id, state) as (
  values 
     (1, 'Florida'),
     (2, 'Georgia')
) 
select * 
from tbl;
```

The use of the `RECORD` keyword  turns both rows into a *single* record if I'm not mistaken. A record can never hold more than one row.

**Edit** (after Craig's comment):

To complete the picture, the following would return exactly the same result albeit without the possibility to specify column names:

```
values 
  (1, 'Florida'),
  (2, 'Georgia');
```

This can be used anywhere a `SELECT` can be used.

Comment: I believe this does actually cover my use case! Maybe I have a misunderstanding on how RECORDs work, but I am still *very* curious how one might utilize ROWs. Thanks much for your time. :)

Comment: @JoshuaBurns: actually I think you cannot use `RECORD` outside of PL/pgSQL but I'm not entirely sure. But `RECORD` always represents a *single* row (record). So I don't think this will work in any way.

Comment: The `VALUES` construct is the correct way to do this. You actually don't need the `WITH` or `SELECT`; `VALUES` is a valid stand-alone query.

Comment: @CraigRinger: how would you give the columns of the `values` clause a name without using the `select` or the cte?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You don't, and they're assigned default names `column1, column2 ... column`*n*. Depending on the calling context you might not care. I'm only pointing this out because people don't often realise that `VALUES` is a stand-alone statement; it's certainly more useful to wrap it but understanding why that works can be valuable.